# In Python pandas , how do i store column name for value_counts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-visualization, data-mining

```
df_da = df_data['State'].value_counts()  
print(df_da)
```

When I print df_da it is not showing any column names? How can I make that it has column names?

Comment: try `df_data['State'].value_counts().reset_index(name='Counts')`

Comment: There's some discussion about this behavior: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11579. `value_counts` returns a Series, with the name of the column you value counted. It's a little odd, because the values are the counts, while the Index of that Series is now the unique column values. You can `df_data.groupby('State').size()` to get a more appropriately named Series.

Answer (score 5):

Reset index and after that you can set columns

```
f_da = df_data['Prefix'].value_counts().reset_index()
df_da.columns = ['Prefix', 'counts']
```